# Tomcat deployment of application with HSQLDB database giving JDBCConnectionException

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, hsqldb

I'm having a struggle with my first attempt with little application based on Spring, Hibernate on HSQLDB and JSF, finally deployed with Tomcat. I face two problems now.

First of all I tried to run Java Application on console based on `main (String args[])` method getting `customerBo` bean from `spring-module.xml` and insert/delete from embedded HSQLDB with Hibernate. Works like a charm.

**1. Two configuration locations**

Another step was a JSF page printing out a sample bean content. Working as well. However I had a struggle with resources and configuration:

- **resources**: Here is all my configuration for database.

  ```
  src/main/resources
     \____ config
             \____ database
                       \____ database.properties
             \____ spring/beans    
                       \____ data-source.xml
                       \____ hibernate-session-factory.xml
     \____ spring-module.xml                            ... for Java Console Application
  ```
- **webapp**: Here is all related to JSF including `WEB-INF` folder` related to web-page alike application.

  ```
  src/main/webapp
     \___ WEB-INF
             \____ applicationContext.xml                        ... for web application
             \____ faces-config.xml
             \____ web.xml
     \___ default.xhtml
  ```

How to make them easily communicate with each other? If web application starts from applicationContext in **webapp**, it needs to work with databse saved in **resources**. So it forces me to prefix all imports etc. with `classpath` such as.

```
<import resource="classpath:/spring-module.xml"/> 
... or ... 
<property name="location">
        <value>classpath:/config/database/database.properties</value>
</property>
```

Java Console application still works well with these decors. Would you suggest me a better way? I import to `applicationContext.xml` all the database-stuff stored int `spring-module.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns=....>
    <import resource="classpath:/spring-module.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:/bean.xml"/>

    <bean id="customerBo" class="nch.spring.customer.bo.impl.CustomerBoImpl"></bean>
</beans>
```

This is the URL I use to connect to HSQLDB

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:database/customers
```

**2. HSQLDB on Tomcat**

I deploy on Tomcat externally, not in IDE. I run `localhost:8080`.

After injecting all beans (working well, because I tested it on console), I recieved an error on Tomcat. Here is the shortened version with the first lines of causing:

> org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hsqldb:database/customers

My database location related to project. It's included in the WAR:

```
project
    \____ src/main/java
    \____ src/main/resources
    \____ src/main/webapp
    \____ database
            \____ customers
                       \____ customers.script
                       \____ customers.lck
                       \____ customers.properties
```

And my pom.xml for HSQLDB:

```
<!-- HSQLDB -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Why I cannot print out the database content with Spring and Hibernate on JSF deployed on Tomcat, but I can print it out on console? Is there an another way to embed a database? Does Tomcat support HSQLDB at all?  I have tried to work first with MySQL, but it had been so cumbersome for me.

---

Shortly:

- HSQLDB works with Spring and Hibernate well, proved on Java Console Application.
- JSF pages working as well, able to print out the content of any bean.

My application refuses to communicate with database since deployed on Tomcat. Here is my full source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/NicharCZ/07_jsf_hibernate).

Comment: Is the HSQLDB connector (containing the JDBC driver) in the classpath of your web application, that is, inside `WEB-INF/lib` of your WAR?

Comment: What do you mean with HSQLDB connector? I include all the database-stuff in `applicationContext.xml` (edited my question).

Comment: The error is telling you that you don't have HSQLDB in the classpath of your web application, and so that Hibernate cannot find the JDBC driver. Are you using Maven to package your WAR? Can you check that this JAR (containing the driver) is inside `WEB-INF/lib` of your WAR?

Comment: I have a Maven project with all the dependencies needed for running HSQLDB (2.3.2 version, edited question again). Proved because it works on console, however not on Tomcat. I don't get why does this error occur.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question in the 2 previous comments about the presence of the library in `WEB-INF/lib`. Also, how are you deploying your WAR? External Tomcat? Inside an IDE?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122051/discussion-between-nikolas-charalambidis-and-tunaki).

Comment: 1) Folder with library included 2) External Tomcat (`localhost:8080`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of the issue is that you're using HSQLDB with a database file, that is actually a resource of your project (i.e. inside its classpath). This means that the file will be embedded inside your WAR, and you will not be able to update it (as contents inside the WAR file will be read-only).

Your connection string for HSQLDB is:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:database/customers
```

When ran inside your IDE, you need to be aware that it does not package your application in a JAR but as an exploded directory. So when you run it as a console application, it will access the database file and update it just fine. However, when packaged in a WAR, it won't find it.

If your intent is to do [read-only on the database](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#rgc_hsqldb_db), you could configure HSQLDB with a [Resource Database URL](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#N1517E)
 of the form

```
jdbc:hsqldb:res:/database/customers
```

> `res`: stored in a Java resource, such as a Jar and always read-only.

This will load a database from the resource located in `/database/customers` of the classpath of your application.

However, if you want to update it, then you have to use another way. A typical way is to use a [Server Database URL](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#N151B1), where the database is hosted on a server, possibly `localhost` for testing purposes.